# Divs are catching on other divs

Tags: css

I have a bunch of toggle buttons with labels underneath.  If the labels for a button get to be too long then what should be the first button of the next row will get stuck on that label.

Heres my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/Android272/c150305z/

I have looked it up and everyone wants to know how to make their site like pintrest. I don't want this to look like that, I want my second and third rows not to be stuck on the first.

some people suggested to place

```
 display: inline-block;
```

somewhere but everywere I place it it does not seem to fix it.

Comment: I dont see any issue on the fiddle. If youre using a fiddle to illustrate a problem you should probably have that problem shown on the fiddle.

Comment: I edited your fiddle and encountered the issue. Adding an `overflow: auto` to the `p` with give it a scroll if the text is too long but the question is how do you want the text presented if it gets too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using unequal heights in your divs.

Set a height to your third section's divs and it will remain equal in row:

```
section:nth-child(3) div {height:110px}
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c150305z/9/)

**Edit**: Another way is to save the spacing by adjusting the `p` but still needs to use `height` for the parent.

This should do:

```
section:nth-child(3) div {
    height:100px; /* Same amount of space as other divs  */
}
section:nth-child(3) div p {
    margin-top:3px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/c150305z/10/)

Comment: That worked but the "section:nth-child(3) div {height:100px;}" made some text I had just laying around move up and is now behind all my buttons.

Comment: section:nth-child(3) div p {
    margin-top:3px;
    line-height: 15px;
}

This did not seem to do anything for me.

Comment: Your layout seems to be limited so the length of text has limitation as well. You need to manually change the height to adjust it to the text.